# Very slow performance on Ubuntu 22.04 with encryption enabled / I/O SSD issue

Tags: 22.04, encryption, macbook-air, io

I have freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Macbook Air 13 Inch Mid-2013. I enabled full disk encryption in the setup process (CPU supports AES-NI, all latest updates installed).

When starting programs it takes very long for them to start up (e.g. Firefox). Also commands in the terminal run very long (e.g. a few minutes for `apt install tmux`) - which should be quite fast. It is to a degree that the system is not usable anymore.

**Some investigation**

Transferring single files is fast:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/admini/temp/test.img bs=5GB count=1 oflag=dsync
```

results in speeds of 480 MB/s

After a bit of digging I notices atop showing low IO performance at times when I also experience a slow system. However, if I run the dd command above, this **does not** slow down the system. Only certain actions on my computer do (e.g. `apt install ...`)

atop while experiencing slow performance (while updating Firefox via the build in Software Center via snap):
[Output of atop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6O8v.png)

```
LVM sda3_crypt busy 88%
LVM gubuntu-root busy 88%
DSK sda busy 91%
```

MB/s read and write are only around 0.0 - 0.2 MB/s. CPU usage at 1%. Memory is 7.7 GB free.

It looks like there is some issue with the SSD, Ubuntu & encryption - however I'm not able to figure out whats going on here and how to fix it. Can you help?

Comment: I don't suppose you have read/write times with the same computer and OS version, but without encryption?  Personally, I'm not surprised that encryption slows the system down a bit.  After all, it doesn't come for free.  Likewise, on-the-fly compression would also slow a system down.  The question is just how much.  Also, a mid-2013 isn't new.  That's why a baseline without encryption but the same computer would be useful.

Comment: `cryptsetup benchmark` results in values above 1200 MB/s for AES - so I guess encryption alone is not the problem. The CPU should not be the bottleneck here.

When the system is "slow" it is not usable anymore. I cannot start any applications, etc. So it's not just slow - it's basically not usable anymore.

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong.  I think what I'm saying is that there are multiple confounding factors.  It would be more convincing to see the same computer, same OS version, same software, ..., everything the same but without encryption.  If you're going to troubleshoot this, probably that's the way to go unless someone else has a better suggestion for you.  (As an aside, Ubuntu was slow for me once -- "unusable" is correct.  `updatedb` was basically indexing my entire hard disk daily.  I stopped it.  You could check to see if anything "disk intensive" is running.)

Comment: Seems to be BUG in ubuntu 22.04 so we are also facing I/O issues https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1973434